# Weird modulo result

Tags: php, modulo

I observed the following and would be thankful for an explanation.

```
$amount = 4.56;
echo ($amount * 100) % 5;
```

outputs : 0

However,

```
$amount = 456;  
echo $amount % 5;
```

outputs : 1

I tried this code on two separate PHP installations, with the same result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the modulo operator work on doubles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect this is because 4.56 can't be exactly represented as a binary floating point number, so a value very close to it is used instead. When multiplied by 100, that comes to 455.999(something), and then the modulo operator truncates down to 455 before performing the operation.

I don't know the exact details of PHP floating point numbers, but the closest IEEE-754 double to 4.56 is 4.55999999999999960920149533194489777088165283203125.

So here's something to try:

```
$amount = 455.999999999;
echo $amount % 5;
```

I strongly suspect that will print 0 too. From [some PHP arithmetic documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! I tried your code and, you were right, it printed 0. And thanks for the documentation part, that's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fmod` to avoid this problem.